# Does Apple Remote Desktop send framebuffer data or rendering commands?

Tags: remote-desktop

Does Apple Remote Desktop send the framebuffer (VNC like) when using remote viewing/control capabilities or does it send rendering commands (RDP like).

Does this differ based on what client is connected (VNC vs. the ARD client)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VNC like. It has several compression schemes, but things like the startfield animation drive it to high bandwidth and very low quality.

This is one area where Windows just kills Mac. I couldn't believe how much more responsive rendering commands were when using RDP. Even windows XP is so much faster for remote access. I can work all day remotely with decent fast ethernet and a fast TS server. Not so on Remote Desktop unless all the stars are "aligned" and off screen so to speak.

Comment: It is disappointing.  Did some searching and NoMachine's NX Server is about to hit 4.0 and will support OS X for the server and client. Unfortunately its very expensive. I did find a link that describes [tunneling MAC's VNC via nxproxy](http://www.chrisk.de/blog/2010/03/how-to-fast-vnc-alternativ-to-remote-desktop-to-a-mac-using-nomachine/), but I think it would still experience the latency that's present on the local network, which with VNC can be as maddening as an internet connection. FreeNX has been quasi abandoned other than maintenance. NeatX from Google could hold some promise.

Comment: While ARD looks like it has all sorts of nice management features, a fast, responsive remote desktop solution for accessing OS X as a remote workstation is really missing at this point.

Comment: I know - i LOVE ARD to death - but it needs gigabit ethernet and low latencies (or low bit depths and low latencies) - you can get work done remotely - just not in full color.